# What machine learning algorithm for predicting inputs to get a certain output

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a simple golf game where the only inputs are angle and power. Submitting these values shoots the ball towards the hole. After the ball stops, a score is created based on the distance between the hole and the ball.

I want to use a machine learning algorithm to predict angle and power values that will give me the perfect score (sinking the ball in the hole).

I understand that I can use a Linear Regression to predict a score based on a chosen angle and power, but I'm not sure how to do it the other way around (get a suggested angle and power from a given score).

Answer (score 0):

Learning of a linear regression model in your case is to solve (a,b,c) in:

score = a * angle + b * power + c

After the training you have values of (a,b,c). When you want to suggest angle and power to obrain particular score you have

[image: power = (score - c - a * angle)/b]

The angle is in range of <0,90), so you can calculate the power needed to use for particular angle to obtain a perfect score.

Comment: Is there a different algorithm that could provide me both power and angle values based on a score? Assuming that I only have a target score, and no angle or power defined?

Comment: You can use kind of k-Nearest Neighbour algorithm for that. Simply get a historical results, where score is closest the target score.